# Is it possible to avoid sloppy seams on vinyl-clad windows?

Tags: windows, vinyl, window-frame

I need to replace some casement windows in my house. I'm leaning towards Andersen. At the showroom, I looked at some aluminum-clad and vynil-clad windows. I noticed that the seams on the vinyl-clad windows look not very good. Why do the seams look like that, can they be sanded down, or can I somehow request that they do a better job cladding the windows?

[image]

Comment: Are you dead-set on Anderson's window products (which are fairly typical of the large US window manufacturers, but not anywhere close to the best you can get your paws on, either in performance or craftsmanship), or is going with a different manufacturer acceptable to you?

Comment: Other manufacturers would be acceptable.

Comment: Frankly I haven't seen seems that bad even on the local home center's house brand. But I wanted wood windows, so I dodged that whole issue.

Comment: If the windows are a decent price point compared to other makes, I would ask for a good discount for the defect.  Once home a soldering iron will smooth those seams out.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel May be off-topic, but what other names should I consider?

Comment: Doesn't matter who makes them if they're made out of vinyl. You're asking for the bottom of the barrel to not be so crappy. Upside is that after it's cased, the reveal on that is only like an inch. I've had to file these down before. And I've replaced 90% of every one of them that I've installed because the handles rip off, then you're pulling it by its case, and then the seal fails on the glass. Do aluminum, unless you just like replacing windows.

Comment: @Wynne -- not going to name any specific manufacturers, but look at European options (their version of a PVC window is very different from ours in several regards)

Comment: @Mazura -- personally, if I was buying a window to last, it'd be hot-rolled steel :P but that's the kind of stuff you buy if you want your windows to still be going strong when your grandkids inherit the house